# Possible to select all visible layers in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Is it possible to select all visible layers in Photoshop, perhaps using a script? I see no way to do so in the Photoshop menu items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the **Layers Panel** to sort based on `Attributes` and then set the second drop down to `Visible`.

Before:
[image]

After
[image]

You can then shift-click to highlight the layers if needed.

Comment: I have been using Photoshop for about 15 years now and never even thought to do this!  Great trick.

Comment: Well, it's only been possible the last couple years @JohnManly :) Requires CC+ I believe.

Comment: I have CC.  I'm a bit of a stubborn old man (mentally anyway) so don't explore the new features much.  I guess I should.  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I overlook those Layers panel features all the time! I can confirm it works on CS6 too. Many thanks, this will do the trick. I was looking for an easy way to select all visible layers so I could then color-code them.

Comment: @Scott any option to view only Hidden/Visible layers?